# What is the memory layout of a QByteArray

Tags: qt, qbytearray

I am trying to find the memory layout of QByteArray (because I have to interface with a DLL, which has QByteArray as parameters).
From the original QT sources, I extracted the following:

```
template <typename BaseClass> struct QGenericAtomicOps {
};
template <int size> struct QBasicAtomicOps : QGenericAtomicOps < QBasicAtomicOps<size> > {
};
template <typename T> struct QAtomicOps : QBasicAtomicOps < sizeof( T ) > {
    typedef T Type;
};
template <typename T>
struct QBasicAtomicInteger {
    typedef QAtomicOps<T> Ops;
    typename Ops::Type _q_value;
};
typedef QBasicAtomicInteger<int> QBasicAtomicInt;
struct RefCount {
    QBasicAtomicInt atomic;
};
typedef void* qptrdiff;
struct QArrayData {
    RefCount ref;
    int size;
    UINT alloc : 31;
    UINT capacityReserved : 1;
    qptrdiff offset; // in bytes from beginning of header
};
template <class T>
struct QTypedArrayData
    : QArrayData {
};
struct QByteArray {
    typedef QTypedArrayData<char> Data;
    Data *d;
};
```

(In this code, I removed all functions, because I'm only interested in the data layout.)

So I assume, that the memory layout is the following:

```
QByteArray
    QArrayData * Data; // pointer to the array-data struct.

QArrayData
    int ref; // the reference counter
    int size; // the used data size
    UINT alloc:31; // the number of bytes allocated
    UINT reserve:1; // unknown
    void* offset; // pointer to real data
```

Is this correct?
I'm especially wondering about 'offset'; from looking at the code I had the impression, that the real data is starting directly after offset and is part of the struct. It also seems to be possible, that the real data is before the 'ArrayData' header.

So 'd' could point to one of these layouts:

```
1. [ref|size|alloc|reserve|offset|--the real data--]
2. [--the real data--|ref|size|alloc|reserve|-offset]
```

Is this correct?

Karl

Comment: Oops, just noticed that in the layout summary, "offset" should be "int" instead of "void*".

Comment: What is the problem in passing the object to the library's interface? What is the purpose of knowing the layout?

Comment: I had to interface to a QT library, but without having the possibility to use that library. Finally I solved the problem by calling low level functions, below the QT layer, in a Win32 DLL. So I still do not know the layout of QT arrays, but it is not necessary anymore.

Comment: This question can be closed now. As noted in my comment, before, I found a workaround without using QT.